# How to show what the /bin directory does using examples?

Tags: raspberrypi

So this is a part of my coursework A452 which states I need to research and ask forums if I don't know the question. I've tried to research this for hours on end and all I find is what the /bin directory does. I know what it does, it's very simple; it's a subdirectory of the root which contains executable files and commands. But how do I use an example to prove this using the terminal? Is there a command I could use to prove it? The full question listed in the coursework is below:

10C) What is the purpose of the bin directory? Use examples to explain this.

Can it please be detailed because the whole thing is worth 30% of my grade however this is the only question I'm stuck on. :((

Comment: Do an `ls /bin`. Pick some commands you think might be commonly used. Run them. QED.

Answer (score 0):

As the directory `/bin` is **one of the several directories containing executables**, you can show this by using the command `which` followed by an executable name in terminal.

**For example:** `which grep`, `which mkdir`, `which date`, etc. (you can pick as you wish from the directory) will all show you that it is in the directory `/bin` (although there are many more in `/usr/bin` for example).